# What is the tens digit of $11!+12!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

In the following problem

> What is the tens digit of $11!+12!$?

I have tried too many times and wasted much time too to find the easiest way by logically.
Please give some idea to find out it and also to find out hundreds digit quickly.
I have these kind of problems too :

> Hundred digit of $123456789^2 $?

Comment: Well, both $11!$ and $12!$ are clearly divisible by $100$ so...

Comment: You have to use modular arithmetic, especially for the second question. So the real question is, what is the value of the expression mod 100.

Comment: You can use modular arithmetic or binomial theorem in second one. First one is divisible by 100. So tens digit will be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT : try using [modular arithmetic](https://brilliant.org/wiki/modular-arithmetic/) ;

For the first one you need to find ;

$11!+12!\mod{100}$

$\implies 11!(13)\equiv0\mod{100}$

so the last 2 digits of $11!+12! $ is $00$

For the second one;

find $(123456789)^2\mod1000$

$(123456000+789)^2\mod1000$

$(123456000)^2+(789)^2+2\cdot123456000\cdot789\equiv (789)^2\mod1000$

$\quad$

we can write $(789)^2 = (700+89)(700+89) = 490000+124600+7921$

$(789)^2\equiv(490000+124600+7921)\mod1000$

$(789)^2\equiv 0+ 600+921 \equiv 1521\equiv521\mod1000$

So last 3 digits are  521.

I'd recommend you check out [this page](https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-the-last-digit-of-a-power/) for more information.

Hope I helped